# Inputting data into a modal from a parent component Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to create a cancel function that cancels a specific viewing based on its id. I have a viewings model that I retrieve from firebase as an observable, I then input it into a child div. The problem being that when I click cancel, it always cancels the first viewing on the page, not the specific one that I click.

The strange thing is, that I created a new component on the same level as my modal component, Input the data in the exact same way, and that works perfectly. It only seems to be with the modal that It does not work.

```
    <div class="col-md-3 buttons" [hidden]='!hidden' [@sliderDiv]="out">
      <button class="button button-primary button-sm button-green text-center"  (click)="updateViewingStatus()">Update Time</button>
      <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancelModal" class="button button-primary button-sm button-previous text-center">Cancel Viewing</button>
</div >
    <viewings-cancel-modal [viewings]="viewings"></viewings-cancel-modal>
    <testing-cancel  [viewings]="viewings"></testing-cancel>
</div>
```

this is where I input viewings property into the child components. Both identical.

this is my test logic (using just a button) that works perfectly:

```
export class TestingCancelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() viewings: TenantViewingModel;
  private viewingsId;
  constructor(private _viewings: ViewingsService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewingsId = this.viewings.viewings_id;
    console.log(this.viewings.viewings_id)
  }

  updateViewingStatus() {
    this._viewings.updateViewingStatus(this.viewingsId);
  }

 }
```

And this is my modal logic (that doesnt work) :

```
export class PropertyViewingsCancelModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() viewings: TenantViewingModel;
  private viewingsId;
  constructor(private _viewings: ViewingsService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewingsId = this.viewings.viewings_id;
    // console.log(this.viewings.viewings_id)
  }

  updateViewingStatus() {
    this._viewings.updateViewingStatus(this.viewingsId);
  }


}
```

Which again are identical. The html for the working button is as follows:

```
<button (click)="updateViewingStatus()"></button>
```

and the non-working modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="cancelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="text-center modal_title"> Are you sure you want to </div>
        <h1 class="text-center" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Cancel Viewing? {{viewingsId}}</h1>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="/assets/img/site/cancel.svg" alt="" style="height: auto; width: 100%; padding: 25px">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <button data-dismiss="modal"  class="button button-primary button-xs button-previous text-center" (click)="updateViewingStatus()">confirm</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
              <button data-dismiss="modal" (click)="logViewings()"  class="button button-primary button-xs button-blue text-center">back</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So just as a re-cap: 
The button test works perfectly, removing the specific viewing that I want to remove or cancel. But with the modal, it only removes the first viewing on the page, even though the logic is identical, and I pass the data through to each child component in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

Here some working example let's try this,

Html File,

```
 <!--Pass your id as argument to your method.-->
 <button (click)="onCancel(id)" class="button button-primary button-sm button-previous text-center">Cancel Viewing</button>

<!--This button has been hiden element is used to call your method -->
<button type="button" class="hideElement" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancelModal" #cancelModal></button>

 <viewings-cancel-modal [viewings]="viewings"></viewings-cancel-modal>
```

Typescript File,

```
import {  ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('cancelModal') private cancelModal: ElementRef;

public onCancel(id:number) {      
       //set some global variable has been id value
        localstorage.setItem("Id",id); //here set value as local storage.
       this.viewings.viewings_id=id;
       this.cancelModal.nativeElement.click();   //then here iam doing call that modal
    }
```

Modal typescript File,

```
export class PropertyViewingsCancelModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() viewings: TenantViewingModel;
  private viewingsId;
  constructor(private _viewings: ViewingsService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.viewingsId = this.viewings.viewings_id;
     this.viewingsId = localstorage.getItem("Id"); //here iam getting id value in localstorage
    console.log("View Id",this.viewingsId) //here you getting your id you can proceed your process in modal button click time.
  }

  updateViewingStatus() {
    this._viewings.updateViewingStatus(this.viewingsId);
  }    
}
```

It is a simple logic you have to implement your convenient. I hope it's helpful to solve your problem.

Thanks,

Muthukumar

Comment: still getting the same issue im afraid! thanks though

Comment: Simply just set local storage and get try once and let me know. iam updated my answer